# Jump to linker errors in quickfix

Tags: quickfix, errorformat

How can I make linker errors jumpable in quickfix?

Example:

```
int foo(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    foo();
}
```

Start up vim and run `:set makeprg=gcc\ %` and try `:make`. This produces a linker error and gives a press enter prompt. If I then check `:copen` the linker error is there but prefixed with `||` and can't be jumped to. I want to be able to jump to the file, or even the reference itself if possible, when linker errors like this occur.

Comment: `:help errorformat`

Comment: Note that a linker error does not contain a reference to a file and line (as a compiler error does), since it's all about combining compiled object files in the final binary: let's say a function definition is missing - where should the cursor jump?

Comment: @VanLaser it should just jump to the file or if it's really fancy to the first reference to the undefined symbol

Comment: The linker only reports that something is missing, or not in order, AFAIK ...   at this stage, the source files were compiled alright, and the linker only sees that `foo()` has no definition. The idea is, linker errors are not *necessarily* a result of something written in your source code (to jump to).

Comment: For example, if you link 64-bit compiled code with a 32-bit library, there is a linker error, but there is no file to jump to.

Comment: @VanLaser The linker knows which object files reference which symbols. The error I get for the above example from gcc: `/tmp/ccQcVJWD.o:test.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'foo'` shows the temporary object file name, source file name, and even the name of the function referencing `foo`. If `foo` exists but there's a 32-64 bit mismatch then, at least with gcc on linux, I still get that error but also get an `incompatible target` error but really if there's a 32-64 bit mismatch, that's a build config error, not a source file error so it's fine if quickfix can't help in that case.

Comment: The 32bit-64bit issue was a(nother) example, not related to `foo()`. If the linker offers file information and some other keyword (such as `foo`), the solution of course involves setting `errorformat` (will probably involve the `%s` item). All I wanted to say was that linker errors won't always offer you even that much information.

Comment: @VanLaser Fair enough, I guess lack of `main` would be one example where there really is nowhere to jump. I'll see about figuring out `errorformat` and posting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting `makeprg=gcc\ -g\ %` instead? The `-g` usually enables enough debug information for the linker to generate line numbers in cases like your example, and then Vim can usually process the output for quickfix.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking to set up a search from the quickfix which as far as I know isn't possible via `errorformat`. However you could write a function to do it and then map that function to a keymap or a command or something.

E.g.

```
function JumpToLinkerError()
    let l:matches = matchlist(getline('.'), '^[^:]*.o:\([^:]*\):.*'
                                         \. "undefined reference to '\\([^']*\\)'")
    sbuffer l:matches[1]
    search('\<' . l:matches[2] . '\>')
endfunction
```

Although this makes some assumptions, such as the idea that 'test.c' is a buffer that you can switch to. Hopefully you can tweak to suit. It also doesn't handle any error conditions... Instead of `sbuffer` maybe `sfind` will work for you but that requires that you have set your `path` correctly and it seems likely to me that if there's a new linker error it's probably in a file you were just editing.

Comment: This also chokes if any of your filenames have colons in them but that sort of thing should be easy to tweak for platform specifics.

Comment: Do you have a succinct argument for why this can't be done via `errorformat`? It would benefit the quality of the answer. I think I came to the same conclusion when I last looked into this but it's been a while so I forget if I had a clear and concrete reason for believing that.

Comment: The first sentence is my succinct answer as to why it's not possible. `errorformat` requires a line number for the jump and the linker error doesn't have one.